# Seperate jar for each module of a multi module maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

Is it possible to generate separate jar file for each module of my multi module maven project.
My project structure

```
- pom.xml (parent pom)
  |
  |-application
  |
  |-module1
  |
  |-module2
```

application module has the main() method. Module1 and module 2 are having REST endpoints that have be consumed by the UI.
Currently when I run mvn package on application module, I get a big fat jar 
having all spring boot dependencies plus the dependencies for each module1 and module 2.

Instead I want to have a separate jar file for module1 and module2. So that when I change code in module1, I don't need to deploy that big fat jar everytime, I need to just deploy module1.jar.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your application is a Spring Boot Application, this is the way it works.

module1 and module2 should both produce jar files in their target folders.

These jar files a pulled in to the application module as dependencies, then that jar is built as a fat or exploded jar.